# Android IAB test: is "RESPOND_NORMALLY" the right license-test answer to test the "real" workflow?

Tags: android, testing, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

According to Android development documentation (see http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html )
there is a field in the developer console settings for Android apps where IAB test-enabled gmail accounts go. There is also a combo box to set the license test answer. Some choices are available, among which "RESPOND_NORMALLY" or "LICENSED". So, it seems that those gmail accounts will not be able to test the "real" IAB workflow, because the answer is chosen by me. Am I wrong? Is "RESPOND_NORMALLY" the choice to test the normal IAB workflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are testing the In App Purchase workflow, there is no difference on which value you set as license test answer, since this value is used only for testing [Licensed applications](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/overview.html) (i.e. for paying apps). You can leave both RESPOND_NORMALLY or LICENSED (I personally left LICENSED).

Comment: Are the gmail addresses I entered in the license test field (near the combo box) useful for in-app purchase test (with managed products that are checked as active on the developer console)? According to your  answer I misunderstood everything, so do I have to create a tester group or community to be able to test in-app purchase?

Comment: Ok, sorry if my answer is not clear. **Yes**, according to [this page](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html) you have to add your testing gmail addresses in the license test field (but, for in-app purchase tests the license test answer makes no difference), and **No**, you don't have to create a tester group or community (but you have to publish the app as Beta or Alpha on the Play Store).